# How to color lattice background in R

Tags: r, lattice, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to color such a plane (areas of lattice: http://postimg.org/image/j37tz50oj/, see below, it is igraph class object) with two colors in this way: starting at the lower corner on the left coloring area with the first color(e.g. blue) until the black contour, then change color to the second one (e.g. grey) until black contour, then change to the first one and so on. Coloring this way would show kind of grey and blue areas separated by black edges. Is this possible to do so with R? How, or what to use?

My code for this:

```
g <- graph.lattice( c(n1,n2), directed=T )
lay <- layout.grid(g)
V(g)$x <- lay[,1]
V(g)$y <- lay[,2]
V(g)$label <- paste(V(g)$x+1, V(g)$y+1, sep=",")

torem <- c(E(g)[ V(g)[x==0] %--% V(g)[x==0] ], 
           E(g)[ V(g)[y==0] %--% V(g)[y==0] ], 
           E(g)[ V(g)[x==(n1-1)] %--% V(g)[x==(n1-1)] ], 
           E(g)[ V(g)[y==(n1-1)] %--% V(g)[y==(n1-1)] ])
g2 <- delete.edges(g, torem)

g3 <- delete.vertices(g2, V(g2)[ x %in% c(0,(n1-1)) & y %in% c(0,(n1-1)) ])
for(i in 1:length(E(g))){
  E(g3)[i]$color <- ifelse((E(g3)[i]$bernoulli==0) || (E(g3)[i]$bernoulli==1)     ,ifelse((E(g3)[i]$bernoulli==0), "white", "black"), "grey")
}
plot(g3,layout=cbind(V(g3)$x, V(g3)$y), vertex.size=1, vertex.shape="none", vertex.color = NA, vertex.label=NA, edge.arrow.size = 0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `symbols(squares=..., inches=FALSE, add=TRUE)`, after creating the plot with the right axes, and before plotting the graph, and then plot the graph with `add=TRUE, rescale=FALSE`.

Please include a (toy) data set in your question and then, I'll include the complete code.

Comment: I've added code. I'm sorry it's long, but I'm quite new with that.

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if you could make it minimal. The details don't matter after all, any piece of code that draws a lattice, is fine.

Comment: `Error in graph.lattice(c(n1, n2), directed = T) : object 'n1' not found` Please make the code work, so that we don't have to edit it.